# ReferenceError: channel is not defined (DISCORD.JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Been following a yt tutorial fort a music bot, I had to update some things for discord.js vs13 and it gave me this error, and the bot says it had an error to connect in the discord chat any help appreciated! (also I tried to define it but no luck, I'm a noob)

This is my code for the music command:

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const discordjsvoice = require('@discordjs/voice')

//Global queue for your bot. Every server will have a key and value pair in this map. { guild.id, queue_constructor{} }
const queue = new Map();

module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    aliases: ['skip', 'stop'], //We are using aliases to run the skip and stop command follow this tutorial if lost: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBUJ3cdofqc
    cooldown: 0,
    description: 'Advanced music bot',
    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord){

        const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: channel.id,
            guildId: channel.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
        });
        
        //Checking for the voicechannel and permissions (you can add more permissions if you like).
        const voice_channel = message.member.voice.channel;
        if (!voice_channel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
        const permissions = voice_channel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');

        //This is our server queue. We are getting this server queue from the global queue.
        const server_queue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

        //If the user has used the play command
        if (cmd === 'play'){
            if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');
            let song = {};

            //If the first argument is a link. Set the song object to have two keys. Title and URl.
            if (ytdl.validateURL(args[0])) {
                const song_info = await ytdl.getInfo(args[0]);
                song = { title: song_info.videoDetails.title, url: song_info.videoDetails.video_url }
            } else {
                //If there was no link, we use keywords to search for a video. Set the song object to have two keys. Title and URl.
                const video_finder = async (query) =>{
                    const video_result = await ytSearch(query);
                    return (video_result.videos.length > 1) ? video_result.videos[0] : null;
                }

                const video = await video_finder(args.join(' '));
                if (video){
                    song = { title: video.title, url: video.url }
                } else {
                     message.channel.send('Error finding video.');
                }
            }

            //If the server queue does not exist (which doesn't for the first video queued) then create a constructor to be added to our global queue.
            if (!server_queue){

                const queue_constructor = {
                    voice_channel: voice_channel,
                    text_channel: message.channel,
                    connection: null,
                    songs: []
                }
                
                //Add our key and value pair into the global queue. We then use this to get our server queue.
                queue.set(message.guild.id, queue_constructor);
                queue_constructor.songs.push(song);
    
                //Establish a connection and play the song with the vide_player function.
                try {
                   
                   
                    queue_constructor.connection = connection;
                    video_player(message.guild, queue_constructor.songs[0]);
                } catch (err) {
                    queue.delete(message.guild.id);
                    message.channel.send('There was an error connecting!');
                    throw err;
                }
            } else{
                server_queue.songs.push(song);
                return message.channel.send(` **${song.title}** added to queue!`);
            }
        }

        else if(cmd === 'skip') skip_song(message, server_queue);
        else if(cmd === 'stop') stop_song(message, server_queue);
    }
    
}

const video_player = async (guild, song) => {
    const song_queue = queue.get(guild.id);

    //If no song is left in the server queue. Leave the voice channel and delete the key and value pair from the global queue.
    if (!song) {
        song_queue.voice_channel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }
    const stream = ytdl(song.url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
    song_queue.connection.play(stream, { seek: 0, volume: 0.5 })
    .on('finish', () => {
        song_queue.songs.shift();
        video_player(guild, song_queue.songs[0]);
    });
    await song_queue.text_channel.send(` Now playing **${song.title}**`)
}

const skip_song = (message, server_queue) => {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
    if(!server_queue){
        return message.channel.send(`There are no songs in queue `);
    }
    server_queue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

const stop_song = (message, server_queue) => {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
    server_queue.songs = [];
    server_queue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}
```

The error:

```
ReferenceError: channel is not defined
    at Object.execute (E:\bot\commands\play.js:17:24)
    at module.exports (E:\bot\events\guild\message.js:13:25)
    at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (E:\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:33:18)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (E:\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (E:\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:350:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (E:\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:443:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (E:\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:300:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (E:\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
```

Answer (score -1):

`channel` variable doesn't exist, try using `voice_channel` instead.

Comment: `message.channel` is a `TextChannel` and OP wants to join a `VoiceChannel` using the `joinVoiceChannel()`.

Comment: You're right, I've edited the answer. Thank you.